# Noun + Noun = Noun (Singular or Plural ?)

Tags: grammar, titles

Which is correct or better for the title of an academic article?

1. Machine learning and cross-validation approaches for the evaluation of anti-spam softwares
2. Machine learning and cross-validation approach for the evaluation of anti-spam softwares

The word approach or approaches is used as noun (not verb) in the title of the article.

Comment: Is not approaches or approach used in the title also noun?

Comment: Please see edit of my question. Actually Machine learning and cross-validation is a single idea, then the noun followed by it should be singular (Approach) or plural (approaches)?

Comment: Yes, if you mean machine learning approach and cross-validation approach, you can use "machine learning and cross-validation approaches".

Comment: If as you say you have a single idea, then you have one approach and  he word is singular, simple. Either way, it's software, not softwares, no matter how many you are evaluating.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin According to [Zwicky](https://arnoldzwicky.org/2011/09/19/software-development/), countification of 'software' has arguably taken place.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear which scenario your paper is describing.

1. An approach that requires a combination technique of machine-learning and cross-validation.
2. Two (or more) approaches , one that uses Machine learning and one that uses cross-validation. Or if your paper contains multiple approaches using both techniques.

---

Case 1: The Machine learning and cross-validation approach for the evaluation of anti-spam software.

Case 2: Machine learning and Cross-validation approaches for the evaluation of anti-spam software.

Let us know which one it is, I'm interested to hear what your writing about!

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, both would be correct if you changed *softwares* to *software*.

You would use *approach* if your article discusses only one approach and this approach is based on both machine learning and cross-validation. In this case, adding "A" at the beginning makes it clearer.

If your article proposes two or more approaches, then *approaches* is correct.